# CakePHP 3 QueryBuilder: condition for few values does not generate 'IN' statement

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2 when you write something like that:

```
$Model->find('all', ['conditions' => ['field' => 1]]);
```

You will get query which looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM model WHERE model.field = 1;
```

Or when you write something like that:

```
$Model->find('all', ['conditions' => ['field' => [1,2,3,5]]]);
```

You will get query which like this:

```
SELECT * FROM model WHERE model.field IN (1,2,3,5);
```

What I mean, is that the 'IN' statement is generated automatically depending on the type of argument.
On the other hand in CakePHP 3 when you write

```
$Table->find()->where(['field' => [1,2,3]])->all();
```

you will receive an error, e.g.

> Cannot convert value to integer

because it generates statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.field = Array();
```

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the official docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatically-creating-in-clauses) you need to indicate the column data type in CakePHP 3:-

```
$Table->find()->where(['field' => [1,2,3], ['field' => 'integer[]']])->all();
```

`integer[]` is telling Cake to expect an array of integers.

Alternatively you can include `IN` in your condition:-

```
$Table->find()->where(['field IN' => [1,2,3]])->all();
```

Both cases will cast the data to an array if it's not already so that the `IN` will work as expected if only an integer value is passed.

Comment: Thanks. I just wonder why it no longer works in previous, simpler way. Is this about performance?

Comment: The way it works in CakePHP 2 is perhaps a little ambiguous and open to abuse. For example, there was no check that an `IN` condition was actually intended, so if an array was passed by mistake it would generate a valid query using an `IN` condition. This change in CakePHP 3 may seem inconvenient, but to me seems a better approach as you should know what your intended conditions should be.

Comment: Just wanted to add that as of 3.1.2 (as best as I can tell), when you forget the "IN" but provide an array argument, you will get a useful "Cannot convert value to string" error instead of a generic exception. I'm mostly saying this so that when I get this error again later and can't remember what it means, this page will come up in the Google results. :-) Hopefully it helps others in the same situation!